# reconstructing a quadratic equation from roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

I have this quadratic equation
$$2x^2+x-3=0$$
that I wish to reconstruct from its roots.
$$D=b^2-4ac=25$$
$$x_1=\frac {-b\pm \sqrt D} {2a} = 1 \text{ and } \frac {-2} 3$$
Now, I've always learned that by taking the product of the roots you get back your original equation.
$$2x^2+x-3=(x-1)(x+1,5)$$
But this is incorrect, and if a do a polynomial long division I get
$$2x^2+x-3=(x-1)*2(x+1,5)$$
So what I've learned appears to be wrong. But what is the correct way? All my old textbooks and online resources tell me nothing of this.

Is it something like this?
$$\text{original quadratic equation}=n(x-x_1)l(x-x_2) \text{ where } n,l \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reconstruct a quadratic equation from its roots, only a *monic*  quadratic equation.

More precisely, if $q(x)=0$ is a quadratic equation with roots $x_1$ and $x_2$, then $q(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ for some $a\ne 0$. The roots do not determine $a$.